# marketing cloud Deployment Manager Error while deploying shared data extensions from one BU to another BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, admin, sfmc-business-unit

I am trying to deploy marketing cloud data extensions and shared data extensions from one BU to another BU using deployment manager. 
I created separate snapshot marketing cloud data extension and shared data extension.
I am able to deploy marketing cloud shared data extensions successfully but unfortunately I getting following error while deploying shared data extensions:
"Could not deploy create new snapshot and deploy stack".
I tried several times to create a snapshot for shared data extension and deploy it.
But always while I am getting the same error :
"could not deploy create new snapshot and deploy stack"
Anybody encountered with this problem?
How to deploy shared data extension using deployment manager?

Please note, I have marketing cloud administrator rights also for development manager I have access to all BU's

Thank You,
Vikram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the shared data extensions belong technically to the root/topmost business unit (this is why you always need to use ENT.[Data extension name] when referencing them in SQL queries). So taking a snapshot of them in e.g. one child BU, and deploying to another child BU will always cause you problems, as you technically ask deployment manager to create same data extensions while they already exist.

You should instead adjust the sharing settings of these data extensions, allowing them to be accessed in your new BU.

Comment: Thank you lukas for details!